# Как восстановить права chmod-ом в системе?

Tags: права, linux, откат, chmod, восстановление

Одним неразумным действием сделал на боевом сервере: `chmod -R 777 /`
Через 2-3 секунды осознал свою великую глупость и прервал, но было уже поздно...
Нет доступа по ssh. Благо есть доступ по VNC-консоль.

Как восстановить права, сделать откат?

Comment: Как всегда, из бэкапа...

(если его нет, значит на самом деле эти данные Вам просто не нужны).

Comment: Установил права 600 на /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key, удалил старый ключ на своей машине и ssh доступ заработал.

Как проверить и восстановить права у остальных папок? Не сверяя каждую вручную с другой системой.

Comment: @Infum

> Не сверяя

Боюсь что никак. Но боевой сервер должен разворачиваться за минуты, включая все веб-приложения, плюс некоторое время на перенос БД - короче, при нормальном использовании конкретная ОС становится просто расходным материалом.

Comment: ![chmod](http://i.imgur.com/miSt5Rn.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

avp, не в бровь, а в глаз прямо. Бэкапа не оказалось с последними изменениями. :(

Но мысль Ваша правильная!

Нашёл решение.

С работающей машины скопировать: find /* | xargs stat -c "%a %n" > list.txt

Восстановить права на испорченной машине: cat ./list.txt | xargs chmod

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за подсказку! Аналогичная проблема возникла, только с chown
Взял из бэкапа права

```
find /var/* | xargs stat -c "%U:%G %n" > /tmp/list.txt
```

Правда восстанавливать пришлось скриптом

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/tmp/list.txt"
while read x1 x2
do
chown $x1 $x2
done < $file
```

Answer (score 0):

Или переустановка, или резервная копия.